# CSS Stepped Rotation on All Axes

Tags: css, css-animations

I want a step-wise rotation of:

1. 180 degrees around the Z-axis;
2. 180 degrees around the Y-axis; and
3. 180 degrees around the X-axis.

So, I've written the CSS:

```
@keyframes rotate {
  25% { transform: rotateZ(180deg); }
  50% { transform: rotateY(180deg); }
  75% { transform: rotateX(180deg); }
}
.content {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 9s;
}
```

However, I can't seem to manage it.
The first rotation (Z) works, but 2. looks like it's rotating around the X-axis not the Y-axis.  And the 3rd rotation, well, that's just weird.

Please can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying this? You should to keep other rotations till the end.

```css
@keyframes rotate {
  33% { transform: rotateZ(180deg); }
  66% { transform: rotateZ(180deg) rotateY(180deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateZ(180deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg); }
}
.content {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 9s;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.content div{
  position: absolute;
}
.content div:nth-child(1){
  width: 45px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  top: 0;
}
.content div:nth-child(2){
  width: 10px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: blue;
  left: 0;
}
.content div:nth-child(3){
  width: 45px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  bottom:0;
}

.content div:nth-child(4){
  width: 10px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: orange;
  right:0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I ran the code snippet and it still didn't work - in IE11 or Edge40.  I then thought "maybe the MS implementation (of 3D rotations) is not the best" so I tested it in Chrome59 and it worked like I wanted/expected.  I think the MS problem may be related to Gimbal Lock but I'm struggling to get my head around that ATM so I can't be sure.  Either way, Edge is gimp.